Openlayers how to dynamically filter layer data with one or more filter values through style variable
I am using latest openlayers version.
I have created layer using WebGLPointsLayer with flatstyle.
I want to build functionality to where user can apply filter to filter data on map.
Below are the scenarios:
When user has not selected any region, it should show all region data.
When user select single region, it should show single region.
When user select multiple regions, it should selected region related data on map. This is not working with dynamic value. It will work when I hardcoded multiple region in a style
Openlayer Doc for Expression: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_expr_expression.html
Hardcode Filter style:
{
  variables: {
    // regionSelected: '',
    multiRegionSelected: [],
    countrySelected: '',
  },
  filter: [
    'all',
    // Single Region selection
    // [
    //   'any',
    //   ['==', ['var', 'regionSelected'], ''],
    //   ['==', ['get', 'region'], ['var', 'regionSelected']],
    // ],

    // Multiple Region selection with hardcoded filter - working fine
    ['in', ['get', 'region'], ['literal', ['MA', 'CA', 'FL']]],
    [
      'any',
      ['==', ['var', 'countrySelected'], ''],
      ['==', ['get', 'country'], ['var', 'countrySelected']],
    ],
  ],
  'circle-radius': [
    'interpolate',
    ['exponential', 2],
    ['zoom'],
    5,
    4,
    15,
    1536,
  ],
  'circle-fill-color': ['match', ['get', 'hover'], 1, '#ff3f3f', '#006688'],
  'circle-displacement': [0, 0],
  'circle-opacity': 0.95,
}

Set dynamic filter value:
{
  variables: {
    // regionSelected: '',
    multiRegionSelected: [],
    countrySelected: '',
  },
  filter: [
    'all',
    // Single Region selection
    // [
    //   'any',
    //   ['==', ['var', 'regionSelected'], ''],
    //   ['==', ['get', 'region'], ['var', 'regionSelected']],
    // ],

    // Multiple Region selection
    // Dynamic filter not working when user select one or more region
    // When user doesn't have any region selected  it should show all region data
    [
      'any',
      ['in', ['get', 'region'], ['literal', ['var', 'multiRegionSelected']]],
      ['==', ['var', 'multiRegionSelected'], 0], // To load all region when no region selected
    ],
    [
      'any',
      ['==', ['var', 'countrySelected'], ''],
      ['==', ['get', 'country'], ['var', 'countrySelected']],
    ],
  ],
  'circle-radius': [
    'interpolate',
    ['exponential', 2],
    ['zoom'],
    5,
    4,
    15,
    1536,
  ],
  'circle-fill-color': ['match', ['get', 'hover'], 1, '#ff3f3f', '#006688'],
  'circle-displacement': [0, 0],
  'circle-opacity': 0.95,
}

To Update style variable dynamically, I have used updateStyleVariables
pointsLayer.updateStyleVariables({
    countrySelected: 'us',
    // regionSelected: 'MA',
    multiRegionSelected: ['MA', 'CA', 'FL'],
  });

Here is the complete example: https://codesandbox.io/s/accessible-forked-vf7w6l
Expected result
When user select one or more region, map data should filter accordingly.

['in', ['get', 'region'], ['literal', [['var', 'region1'], ['var', 'region2'], ['var', 'region3']]]], will work if you can manage with a finite number of entries.

Thanks @Mike, for your suggestion, but region selection is dynamic(based on user selection), so no control. User may select one, two....till available options.
